# is the output of an aggregator in informatica always sorted?

Tags: sorting, informatica-powercenter, aggregator

Is the output of an aggregator component in Informatica always going to be sorted by the group specified, also when the input sorted box is not ticked, and the component does the grouping itself? Or is there no guarantee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input to the aggregator transformation is not sorted, then the output will also not be sorted.

As for your other question, even if you do not use sorted input , aggregator transformation will group by just fine. It might only impact performance.

Comment: hi, thanks, actually I had just that one question, but you answered it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rusty
 If the data is not sorted, aggregator will not sort it. If it is sorted already before passing to the aggregator transformation, check the sorted option as it increases the execution speed. To have fun on informatica, play with https://etlinfromatica.wordpress.com/